# How to get asp.net hidden fields values with node js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to login in to a site with `nodejs`.
The site's `asp.net` login form has hidden fields:
`__EVENTTARGET, __EVENTVALILDATION, __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTARGUMENT`

I am trying the following code:

```
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0'; // Ignore 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' authorization error

var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

function postback(url, callback) {
    request.get(url, function onResponse(err, res, body) {
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var button = callback(err, $);
        if (button) {
            var form = {
                //__EVENTTARGET: button.attr('form1').match(/['"]([^"^']+)/)[0], // TODO image buttons
                __EVENTTARGET: button.attr('Button1'),
                __VIEWSTATE: $('#__VIEWSTATE').val(),
                __EVENTVALIDATION: $('#__EVENTVALIDATION').val(),
                __EVENTARGUMENT: $('__EVENTARGUMENT').val(),
            };
        }
    });
}

postback('https://example.com', function(err, $) {
    var button=$('input[type="image"]');
    return button
    //console.log(err)
    //console.log($)
})
```

It's not getting the values of `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT`.
These fields may needs a button click.
How to click it with cheerio?